# SQLite with Entity Framework 6 "no such table"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm trying to implement [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923115/how-to-search-large-amount-of-data-based-on-tags) with **SQLite** and **EntityFramework 6** code first. I can create the database and there is a file (although empty), but when I try to add an entry to the database it says there is no such table. Yet, when I try to create the table manually (`db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE etc.)`) it tells me that the table already exists.

I found some questions about this already, but they're all about the path not being absolute, which is simply not the case here.

## Context

```
//Context:
class MediaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MediaModel> Media { get; set; }

    public MediaContext(string filename): base(new SQLiteConnection() {
        ConnectionString =
            new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
            { DataSource = filename, ForeignKeys = false }
            .ConnectionString
    }, true)
    {

    }        
}
```

## DAL

```
//In the DAL:
public DataAccessLayer(string path)
{
   _path = Path.GetFullPath(path); //<--The path already comes full in, I'm just paranoid at this point.
   _connectionPath = _path + @"\MyDatabase.sqlite";

   using (var db = new MediaContext(_connectionPath))
   {
      db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
      db.Database.Initialize(false);                

       db.SaveChanges();
   }

   public void Generate()
   {
       using (var db = new MediaContext(_connectionPath))
       {
          db.Media.Add(new MediaModel("test"));
          db.SaveChanges(); //<--SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database: no such table: MediaModels

        }
    }
```

## App.Config

```
//App.config:
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v13.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That doesn't change a thing with my problem. :/

Comment: Try to use the SQLite Browser app to see if the table is indeed there and if it has the right schema

Comment: If I open the file with Notepad++ it is completely empty (0kB). I once managed to create it somehow, but I'm not able to reproduce this anymore (so I can't check that one). Then it had 8kB and was filled with lots of NUL chars. So I guess it's a problem with the creation and saving of the table, but as mentioned in the question I can't create it manually either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like ErikEJ said does SQLite not support code first in they way I use it, and apparently it has a strict naming policy.

To make it all work I had to manually create the table, and adapt the context to the naming schema (`Media` => `MediaModels`).

## Context

```
public DbSet<MediaModel> MediaModels { get; set; }
```

## DAL

```
public DataAccessLayer(string path)
{
    _path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    _connectionPath = _path + @"\MyDatabase.sqlite";
    
    using (var db = new MediaContext(_connectionPath))
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'MediaModels' ('Name' TEXT, 'FilePath' TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 'Tags' TEXT, 'Note' TEXT, 'FileExtension' TEXT)");

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
    
public void Generate()
{
    using (var db = new MediaContext(_connectionPath))
    {
        db.MediaModels.Add(new MediaModel("test"));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

That code is still not perfect, and I'll try to update this answer as I improve it.

Answer (score 26):

I have got Code First approach working inspired by this post:
[Create SQLite DB using Entity Framework Core Code First](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/create-sqlite-db-entity-framework-core-code-first/)

The trick is to have a call to EnsureCreated in the context constructor:

```
    public MediaContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```

---

Regarding the table name to property name matching:
You can use the `Table`attribute to make things work:

```
public DbSet<MediaModel> Media { get; set; }
```

and explicitly specify the table name in your model class although this seems redundant:

```
[Table("MediaModel")]
public class MediaModel
```

Comment: EnsureCreated is exclusive for core version but EF6 don't

Comment: If you are using migrations with new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:") connection then, migrations will be ignored and you have to use "Database.EnsureCreated()". Thanks +1

Answer (score 8):

The SQLite provider for EF6 does not support Code First / Migrations workflow, so you must manually create the database outside of your EF6 workflow.

Comment: I tried that, even checked your comment as an answer, however although I now have data in the file, and it seems to fill with normal queries, I can still not use it with EF6. It has the same error as before: "no such table: MediaModels". What is bugging me is that at no place I'm even asking for a "MediaModels" table. Could there be something wrong with my context?

Comment: You probably need to specify the table name explicitly in your context using the fluent mapping api or the Table attribute

Answer (score 7):

This is the recommended reply from [Microsoft itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio):

> Visual Studio uses an inconsistent working directory when running .NET
>   Core console apps. (see dotnet/project-system#3619) This results in an
>   exception being thrown: `no such table: Blogs.` To update the working
>   directory:
>
> Right-click on the project and select Edit Project File
>
> Just below the TargetFramework property, add the following:
>
> `<StartWorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</StartWorkingDirectory>`
>
> Save the file
>
> Now you can run the app:
>
> Debug > Start Without Debugging

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. The issue remains.
Same comment in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/index?tabs=visual-studio, but it does not work

Answer (score -1):

I'm using .NET Core and EntityFramework Core 2 and code first migration for SQLite.
Specifying table name in `OnModelCreating` helped to solve the issue:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .ToTable(typeof(File).Name + "s") // <-- the argument could be just "Files"
            .HasKey(lf => new { lf.MachineName, lf.PathName });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Another option - `TableAttribute` also should have helped:

```
    [Table("Files")]
    public class File
    {
        // ...
    }
```

`OnModelCreating` will override table name specified in `TableAttribute` if both are specified.