# Entity Framework Core error DbUpdateException - I cant add element do database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn EF and for two days now I can't move on. When I try to add an element to the database, I get this error

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details

I'm learning from the official MS tutorial: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli). My code is the same.

The database is created but I can't add a thing to it - every time I have the same error. Please, any suggestion will be helpful.

I've tried to do other tutorial and same error still occurs.

Comment: Well - the error message tells you to *see the inner exception for details* - have you inspected that/those inner exception(s) ? They tend to be quite specific about what the problem is ......

Comment: Thank you for your advise, my application is finally up and running! The error was: "no such table: Blogs". I found the solution in the other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111572/20594065
So I basically had to paste the following line under the TargetFramework property in the working directory file:
<StartWorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</StartWorkingDirectory>